# Python group by 2 columns but get records vary by a different column

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which has 3 columns, ZIP_CODE, TERR_NAME, STATE.  For a given ZIP_CODE & TERR_NAME, there can be only one STATE code.  There can be duplicate records exists, but not a record with same ZIP_CODE/TERR_NAME and 2 different STATEs?  How can i get the error records please.

I tried to group by ZIP_CODE/TERR_NAME/STATE but not getting idea on getting these errorneous records.

```
df1= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ"),("81A01","TERR NAME 01","CA"),("81A02","TERR NAME 02","NY"),("81A03","TERR NAME 03","NY"), ("81A03","TERR NAME 03","CA"), ("81A04","TERR NAME 04","FL"), ("81A05","TERR NAME 05","NJ"), ("81A06","TERR NAME 06","CA"), ("81A06","TERR NAME 06","CA")], ["zip_code","territory_name","state"])

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1_temp")
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
|zip_code|territory_name|state| 
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
| 81A01| TERR NAME 01| NJ| 
| 81A01| TERR NAME 01| CA| 
| 81A02| TERR NAME 02| NY| 
| 81A03| TERR NAME 03| NY| 
| 81A03| TERR NAME 03| CA| 
| 81A04| TERR NAME 04| FL| 
| 81A05| TERR NAME 05| NJ| 
| 81A06| TERR NAME 06| CA| 
| 81A06| TERR NAME 06| CA|
+--------+--------------+-----+
```

I need a dataframe without these codesm i.e., 81A01, 81A03 which has same zip_code, territory name but with different STATE codes using spark.sql().

Expected new DF:

```
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
|zip_code|territory_name|state| 
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
| 81A02| TERR NAME 02| NY| 
| 81A04| TERR NAME 04| FL| 
| 81A05| TERR NAME 05| NJ| 
| 81A06| TERR NAME 06| CA| 
| 81A06| TERR NAME 06| CA|
+--------+--------------+-----+
```

Excluded ZIPCODES:

```
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
|zip_code|territory_name|state| 
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
| 81A01| TERR NAME 01| NJ| 
| 81A01| TERR NAME 01| CA| 
| 81A03| TERR NAME 03| NY| 
| 81A03| TERR NAME 03| CA| 
+--------+--------------+-----+
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself, publishing here so it may be useful for others:

```
spark.sql("SELECT zip_code, territory_name, COUNT(distinct state) as COUNT FROM df1_temp GROUP BY zip_code, territory_name having COUNT>1").show()

+--------+--------------+-----+ 
|zip_code|territory_name|COUNT| 
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
| 81A03| TERR NAME 03| 2| 
| 81A01| TERR NAME 01| 2| 
+--------+--------------+-----+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {
    "zip_code":["81A01", "81A01", "81A02", "81A03", "81A03", "81A04", "81A05", 
    "81A06", "81A06"],
    "territory_name": ["TERR NAME 01", "TERR NAME 01", "TERR NAME 02", 
    "TERR NAME 03", "TERR NAME 03", "TERR NAME 04", "TERR NAME 05", 
    "TERR NAME 06", "TERR NAME 06"], 
    "state": ["NJ", "CA", "NY", "NY", "CA", "FL", "NJ", "CA", "CA"]  
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


duplicate = list(set([tuple(df[(df["zip_code"] == df["zip_code"][i]) & 
           (df["territory_name"] == df["territory_name"][i])].index) for i in 
           range(len(df))]))


for i in duplicate:
    if len(i) > 1:
        if not df["state"][i[0]] == df["state"][i[1]]:
            df = df.drop(i[0])
            df = df.drop(i[1])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key,group_df in df.groupby(['zip_code','territory_name']):


    if len(group_df)>1:
      print(key)
```

I hope the above code solves your problem

Comment: hi thanks, but i got an error "'GroupedData' object is not iterable".  I have a tableview created, can you please help me with an SQL query equivalent.  Also please note i need a dataframe only where the 3rd column data is different.

Comment: select zip_code,territory_came from table_name group by 'zip_code','territory_name' having count('zip_code','territory_name') >1

Answer (score 0):

> **With Pyspark :**
>   Here the code snippet as per your requirement.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df1= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ"),("81A01","TERR NAME 01","CA"),("81A02","TERR NAME 02","NY"),("81A03","TERR NAME 03","NY"), ("81A03","TERR NAME 03","CA"), ("81A04","TERR NAME 04","FL"), ("81A05","TERR NAME 05","NJ"), ("81A06","TERR NAME 06","CA"), ("81A06","TERR NAME 06","CA")], ["zip_code","territory_name","state"])
df1_v1 = df1.withColumn("avg", collect_set("state").over(Window.partitionBy("zip_code","territory_name").orderBy("zip_code"))).filter(size(col("avg"))==1).orderBy(col("zip_code")).drop(col("avg"))

df1_v1.show()
```

let me know if you face any issue related to the same and if it solves your purpose accept the answer.

[image]